# Trying to remove a warning in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

i have use below code in my application.  However, I am getting a warning, and I am not sure why.  My code is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        if (textField.tag == 1) {

            if(blah blah blah)
                return YES;

            //more code

            if (blah blah) {

                //more code

            }

            else if (blah blah) {

                //more code;

            }

            else if (blah blah blah) {

                //more code

            }


            //even more code

            return NO;

        }

        else if (textField.tag == 2){

            if(textField.text.length > 1) {

                return NO;

            }

            return YES;

        }

        else if (textField.tag == 3) {

            if(textField.text.length > 2) {

                return NO;

            }

            return YES;

        }


    }
```

The warning I'm getting is:

"Control may reach end of non-void function."  I have return values at the end of each "if" clause, so why am I still getting this warning?

Comment: You have to put a return statement in the end after all the blocks end before the function ends.. It will work as default response to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function should receive a boolean value as your function has return type BOOL not void put

```
return YES;
```

at the end of `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:()` method out side of the conditional/iterative statements.

then warning should go.

Answer (score 2):

> I have return values at the end of each "if" clause

No, you don't. The very last `else` branch is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return YES/NO;` at the end of you method. might be solve your problem. because if any of your
`if - condition - Block` is not execute then this method has not return value.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is seeing that if `textfield.tag` is not 1, 2 or 3 there is no return value. Add return YES/NO at the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
    {
        if (textField.tag == 1)
        {

          if(blah blah blah)
            return YES;

        //more code

          if (blah blah)
          {

            //more code

          }

          else if (blah blah)
          {

            //more code;

          }

          else if (blah blah blah)
          {

            //more code

          }


         //even more code

         return NO;

        }

        else if (textField.tag == 2)
        {

         if(textField.text.length > 1) 
         {

            return NO;

        }

        return YES;

      }

    else if (textField.tag == 3) {

        if(textField.text.length > 2) {

            return NO;

        }

        return YES;

      }

    }
return YES;
}
```